# How to display only the rows in the csv file which contain the input value, with alignment using python 3.6.1

Tags: python, csv, input, row

I cannot seem to find the input value in the csv file and only display the rows containing the input value.
The alignment of the csv data with the printed headers is also an issue I am struggling to solve.

```
import csv

def menu():
        print("Menu") #Prints menu page to select option
        print("======")
        print("[1]: Display info")
        print("[0]: Exit")

def info():
    read = csv.reader(open("value.csv", "r"))
    for j in read:
        print(j[:4])

while True:
    menu()
    selection = int(input("Enter your selection: ")) #Choose selection from menu

    if selection == 1:
        print("1: Display info")
        print()
        Num = str(input("Enter a value.: ")) #Input value to find for match, refers to the Value in value.csv file
        print("{:<10}{:<15}{:<15}{:<11}".format("Value", "Time", "Distance", "Pace")) #Prints heading
        print("{:<10}{:<15}{:<15}{:<11}".format("--------", "-------------", "-------------", "---------")) #Prints heading with alignment
        info() #Executes def function

    elif selection == 0:
        break #Exit from program
```

Comment: How do you expect it to work? You don't even pass `Num` to `info`.

Answer (score 0):

could you use the following code?

## finder.py

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

tofind = input("String to find:")

print("{:<10}{:<10}".format("Index", "Value"))

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for index, value in content:
        if ( value == tofind ):
            print("{:<10}{:<10}".format(index, value))
```

## data.csv

```
1,test
2,ok
3,findme
4,test
5,random
6,findme
7,findme
8,no
9,yes
10,findme
```

## Output

```
➜  python python3 finder.py
String to find:yes
Index     Value     
9         yes       
➜  python python3 finder.py
String to find:findme
Index     Value     
3         findme    
6         findme    
7         findme    
10        findme
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting problem is simple to solve.

Your code formats your headings like this:

```
print("{:<10}{:<15}{:<15}{:<11}".format("Value", "Time", "Distance", "Pace"))
```

but the function that prints the data does no formatting at all:

```
print(j[:4])
```

If you want the data to line up with the headings you need to format it that way:

```
print("{:<10}{:<15}{:<15}{:<11}".format(*j[:4]))
```

Though it is usual to have numbers, and the column headings above them, right-aligned not left-aligned (`>` not `<`), and my personal preference is to centre dates and times (`^` not `<`).

COLDSPEED has already answered your other question. The function `info()` lists everything in the `.csv` file. If you want to filter on the value of `Num` then you need to pass `Num` to the `info()` function and perform an `if`-test in that function to select the data the user wants to see.

We can't tell what that `if`-test should be. Is `Num` supposed to be a value in the file (if so, which one? distance, maybe?), or what? In other words, on what basis do you want the selection to happen? That needs to be in your question if you want an answer.